# No carga Interstitial admob en Swift

Tags: swift, admob

Buenas, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se pulse un botón se despliegue una vista con publicidad para ser mas exactos Interstitial de AdMob. Tengo un problema ya que el botón esta en una vista y cuando le acciono me salta este error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` y la aplicación deja de funcionar.

Dejo el código.

```
var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
func createAndLoadAd() -> GADInterstitial {
    let ad = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "XXX-XXX-XXX")

    let request = GADRequest()

    request.testDevices = ["XXXXXXXXXXXXX"]
    ad.loadRequest(request)

    return ad
}

func MuestraPublicidad() {
        if (self.interstitial.isReady)
        {
            self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
            self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAd()
        }
}
```

En La UIview lo he echo de la siguiente manera

```
let VistaPrincipal = ViewController()
VistaPrincipal.MuestraPublicidad()
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás intentando presentar el `interstitial` antes de crearlo, es decir, cambia esto:

```
self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAd()
```

por esto

```
self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAd()
self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
```

Debería funcionar, ya que `var interstitial: GADInterstitial!` no existe cuando intentas mostrarlo

**Actualización 1**

También puede ser que debas verificar si `var interstitial: GADInterstitial!` existe. Para hacerlo, puedes modificar el código tal que así:

```
if let inter = self.interstitial { // Nos aseguramos que exista
    inter.presentFromRootViewController(self)
}
```

Comment: No funciona sigue el error pero si  if (self.interstitial.isReady)
        {
            self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
            self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAd()
        }                                                                                                                       Pero si esto lo pongo en un bobote en el ViewController funciona sin ninguna problema

Comment: Pero lo que no tiene sentido es que intentes hacer "presentFromRootViewController" antes de inicializar "var interstitial". Por tanto, o "var interstitial" se inicia antes de utilizarlo o debes borrar "self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadAd()" porque estás reinicializando la variable

Comment: si La vista esta creada pero donde da el error es aquí Vista.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(Vista.self)

Comment: He añadido otra opción que debes verificar

Comment: Si ya no da ninguna error solo que no muestra la Vista

Comment: Claro, no te da error porque se verifica si existe "interstitial", pero como no existe, no se llega a ejecutar nunca "presentFromRootViewController(self)". Por tanto, "interstitial" no existe y hay que inicializarla antes de utilizarla